# elixir/phoenix ecto how to judge return condition?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Given the code

```
def getbno() do
  query = from u in GodowentryForAcceptance,
    select: max(u.bno)
  Repo.one(query)
end
```

I want to judge return condition such as

```
case GodownentryForAcceptanceService.getbno() do
  empty-> do something
  notempty -> dosomething
end
```

What is judge condition(empty/not empty)?

Comment: i have konw nil(empty),not emtpy(_)

Comment: What do you mean by "judge condition"? For empty you can do `nil ->` and for not empty, use any variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Acording to the docs, [`Repo.one/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:one/2) returns `nil` if no result was found. So in order to check for it you could do something like this (as @Dogbert mentioned):

```
case GodownentryForAcceptanceService.getbno() do
  nil -> do_something() # empty
  value -> dosomething(value) # not empty
end
```

Also note that, if more than one result is found in the query, `Repo.one/2` raises an error (`Ecto.MultipleResultsError`).